# Ambari Hive UTF-8 problems

Tags: hadoop, encoding, utf-8, hive, ambari

Have a problem with cyrillic symbols at hive tables. Installed versions:

```
ambari-server 2.4.2.0-136
hive-2-5-3-0-37 1.2.1000.2.5.3.0-37
Ubuntu 14.04
```

Whats the problem:

1. Set locale to ru_RU.UTF-8:

   ```
   spark@hadoop:~$ locale
   LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
   LANGUAGE=ru_RU:ru
   LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
   LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
   LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
   LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
   LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
   LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
   LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
   LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
   LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
   LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
   LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
   LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
   LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8
   ```
2. Connect to hive and create test table:

   ```
   spark@hadoop:~$ beeline -n spark -u jdbc:hive2://spark@hadoop.domain.com:10000/

   Connecting to enter code herejdbc:hive2://spark@hadoop.domain.com:10000/
   Connected to: Apache Hive (version 1.2.1000.2.5.3.0-37)
   Driver: Hive JDBC (version 1.2.1000.2.5.3.0-37)
   Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
   Beeline version 1.2.1000.2.5.3.0-37 by Apache Hive

   0: jdbc:hive2://spark@hadoop.domain.com> CREATE TABLE `test`(`name` string) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'serialization.encoding'='UTF-8');
   No rows affected (0,127 seconds)
   ```
3. Insert cyrillic symbols:

   ```
   0: jdbc:hive2://spark@hadoop.domain.com> insert into test values('привет');

   INFO  : Tez session hasn't been created yet. Opening session
   INFO  : Dag name: insert into test values('привет')(Stage-1)
   INFO  :

   INFO  : Status: Running (Executing on YARN cluster with App id application_1490211406894_2481)

   INFO  : Map 1: -/-
   INFO  : Map 1: 0/1
   INFO  : Map 1: 0(+1)/1
   INFO  : Map 1: 1/1
   INFO  : Loading data to table default.test from hdfs://hadoop.domain.com:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/test/.hive-staging_hive_2017-03-23_13-41-46_215_3133047104896717605-116/-ext-10000
   INFO  : Table default.test stats: [numFiles=1, numRows=1, totalSize=7, rawDataSize=6]
   No rows affected (6,652 seconds)
   ```
4. Select from table:

   ```
   0: jdbc:hive2://spark@hadoop.domain.com> select * from test;
   +------------+--+
   | test.name  |
   +------------+--+
   | ?@825B     |
   +------------+--+
   1 row selected (0,162 seconds)
   ```

I've read a lot of bugs at apache hive, tested unicode, utf-8, utf-16, some isos encodings with no luck.

Can somebody help me with that?

Thanks!

Comment: Cyrillic Small Letter Pe `п` (unicode `U+043F`) ==> Question Mark `?` (unicode   `U+003F`),  Cyrillic Small Letter Er `р` (`U+0440`) ==> `@` (`U+0040`) etc. etc. The highest Unicode byte lost in all characters…

Comment: @JosefZ thx - some new information for me. Any ideas how to deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

Guys from Hortonwroks helped me with that issue. Seems that it's a bug.

https://community.hortonworks.com/answers/90989/view.html

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13983